# Django makemigrations error

Tags: python, django

Hi everybody I have a problem regarding database migrations. I am trying to switch from 2.7 to 3.4 and this is what I get when I makemigrations

[image]

```
adgc@mnl-adgc-pc1:~/Desktop/people$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 125, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 43, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 186, in _detect_changes
    self.generate_altered_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 850, in generate_altered_fields
    if old_field_dec != new_field_dec:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/validators.py", line 55, in __eq__
    self.regex.pattern == other.regex.pattern and
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'pattern'
```

Comment: which django version are you using?

Comment: @Alasdair Ok will do in a moment

Comment: @doniyor, I am using django 1.8

Comment: please show your models

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django on python2 create migration with byte-strings in code:

```
apps/post/migrations/0001_initial.py:                ('picture', models.ImageField(upload_to=b'images/posts/%Y_%m/%d', null=True, verbose_name='Picture', blank=True)),
apps/post/migrations/0001_initial.py:                ('lang_code', models.ForeignKey(default=b'en', verbose_name='Language', to='account.Language')),
```

And when we run it in python3 environ it crashes.

```
$ find apps -type f -exec sed -i "s/{b'/{'/g" {} \;        
$ find apps -type f -exec sed -i "s/(b'/('/g" {} \;
$ find apps -type f -exec sed -i "s/ b'/ '/g" {} \;
$ find apps -type f -exec sed -i "s/=b'/='/g" {} \;
$ find apps -type f -exec sed -i "s/\[b'/\['/g" {} \;
```

[See it over here too](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24651#comment:3)

Comment: you got that one from django tickets right? Tried that one but no luck. But might as well try it again

Comment: Yeah I've mentioned that in the links

Comment: It's working now! And the reason why it didn't work on my first time is because I just tried one of these 5 commands. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're most welcome for further reason regarding your problem go to [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/#syntax-requirements]